# Missing Windows Settings

Tags: windows-10

I have three Laptops with different Windows 10 settings.  On my first Laptop, I have the settings I need; I could find them and set up everything as I wanted.

On my second and third, some settings are just missing.  For example, I couldn't find the setting 'disable touchpad when mouse is active' or the option 'activate(disactivate) touchpad tricks'.

How can I find or create these settings?

EDIT:
My Windows:
[image]

I don't have the settings, how do I get these back: 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to auto disable touchpad when mouse is active? If so, you can refer to:https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-touchpad-while-mouse-connected-windows-10

Comment: Do you means your three laptops all have win10 but with different settings. You want them have the same settings? If so, please ensure that they have the same version name. You can update the system to the latest version first and check whether the issue still exist.

Comment: @Peter.G I've Edited ... so you can understand better.

Comment: A the three Laptops identical in hardware and drivers?

Comment: @harrymc no they aren't ... different producers, processors, names everything ...

Comment: If I cannot read the text in a screenshot then I cannot explain the behavior in the screenshot.  We also don’t know enough about your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

As the laptops are not identical, they have different hardware and different
drivers for that hardware.

It is quite logical for different drivers to have different capabilities,
which are reflected in having different settings.

Comment: But why isn't the 'disable touchpad when mouse active' option showed?, Or change cursor speed? Are all settings hardware related?

Comment: Settings are dictated by both the driver and the hardware. You may search for newer drivers on the website of the manufacturer of the touchpad, if those chosen by Microsoft are too basic. If no such drivers exists, or if they don't help, there isn't much you can do.